# Can't access array via $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following html code:

```
<form method="post" action="arrayplay.php">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"/>
</form>
```

And the following PHP script:
//arrayplay.php

```
foreach ($_POST['todelete'] as $id)
{
echo $id . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

It is supposed to echo out each element value but instead I get an error. I am getting really frustrated. If I use:

```
<form method="post" action="arrayplay.php">
<?php
$dbc= //connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM email_list";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] . '" name="todelete[]" />';
echo $row['first_name'];
echo ' ' . $row['last_name'];
echo ' ' . $row['email'];
echo '<br />';
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" />
</form>
```

It works perfectly fine! Why? The first (hard coded html) holds the exact same value as the one that retrieves them from the database. I am having a real hard time understanding retrieving values from an array with $_POST. Why does name=foo[] create an array? Is it an associative or numeric array? I'm sorry for all of the questions, I'm just really ready to pull my hair out.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Consider as well that we get frustrated when an error is mentioned, but not provided and/or specifically described. What is the error? Is there an error message?

Comment: `I get an error`. Please elaborate...

Comment: If in doubt, var_dump the variable. What is the output?

Comment: Note that the checkboxes will be passed in $_POST only if they are checked.

Answer (score 0):

if you just named the input `foo` it would only get one value. because square brackets are commonly used for arrays, `foo[]` is how in the html form, you indicate an array. of course on the PHP side you just call it `foo` as you are aware from your working example.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it should work:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['delete']) {
    foreach ($_POST['todelete'] as $id) {
            echo $id.' selected<br />';
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="arrayplay.php">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="todelete[]"/>
<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"/>
</form>
```

If you're still having troubles, you can try:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['delete']) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        if (isset($_POST['todelete'][$i])) {
            echo $_POST['todelete'][$i].' selected<br />';
        }
    }
}
?>
```